# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError When Running A Code From External .jar

Tags: scala, nosuchmethoderror

I have a piece of code that throws java.lang.NoSuchMethodError on runtime that I could not resolve:

```
 private def saveActivationEvent(event: ActivationEvent) = activationEventService.createIfFirst(event)
```

Implementations:

```
case class ActivationEvent extends Event 

class ActivationEventService extends AbstractEventService[ActivationEvent]

abstract class AbstractExalateEventService[E <: Event] {
 def createIfFirst(event: E)(implicit reader: BSONDocumentReader[E], writer: BSONDocumentWriter[E]): Future[Option[BSONObjectID]] = ...
}
```

I thought it was happening because of the type erasure... Could someone help me to understand the problem?

Comment: This is almost certainly not happening because of type erasure. It could be happening because someone's trying to work around type erasure irresponsibly, but it's hard to tell whether that's the case without a complete working example and more info about your compile and runtime dependency versions.

Comment: NoSuchMethodError almost always occur when the code is compiled against a jar file whose version does not match the one that is used at runtime.

Comment: @TravisBrown, thank you for the response. It was indeed a problem with the  compile and runtime versions of the dependency .jar . If you put it in an answer, I could accept it ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I mention in a comment above, any time you see a `NoSuchMethodError`, the first thing you should check is that your compile and runtime dependency versions match. For what it's worth I can't think of a way that type erasure could have anything to do with a `NoSuchMethodError`—you may see a `ClassCastException` if someone has a bad type test that matches because of erasure, but even in that case the problem isn't really the erasure, it's the fact that someone is trying to work around it (and ignored the compiler's warnings).